# How can I change header color when scrollbar has moved or menu item was clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a one page website, and I am already using scroll spy to allow my webpage to scroll directly to the div ID when the menu item is clicked. I am looking to take this one step further and actually change the color of the header. The header is a transparent color right now so I want to change it to a solid color as soon as the scroll bar moves or menu item is clicked, and then change it back when it is at the top of the page.

How would one go about doing this with Jquery? I have seen sites doing this although I can't find an example. Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Can you show an example site?

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this with jquery scroll function and some css3 transitions (if you want the color to fade in)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
    $(".header").addClass("scroll");  
  }else{
    $(".header").removeClass("scroll");  
  };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ8H6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any examples?  Could you possibly fiddle it?

**http://jsfiddle.net/RG3m7/** - Something like this could be what you're after.  If so, very simple.

```
$(function() {                  
  $(".content").click(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("active");   
  });
});
```

**Updated** - This will remove the class when you select another.  Hopefully it helps?  Sorry if I'm missing :)

```
$(function() {
  $(".content").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".content.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

**NEW - http://jsfiddle.net/RG3m7/1/**

Comment: $(".thing").on("click", function() { // stuff });

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use cases and what kind of features you are looking for, a great jQuery plugin is Waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/